# How To Achieve This Type of Page Border

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, page-layout, website-templates

I'm taking this website as an example: [BuddyMiller.com](http://buddymiller.com/)

[image: Example image]

Is that border that looks like a nice persian rug, surrounding the page, something I would get from a template online (I've been searching for hours and can't find anything remotely close) and if so could you point me to some website which has these type of page border templates (not bad-looking clip-art, but nice like this).

Or is this something I can do in Photoshop, and if so how would it be done or is there a good tutorial out there you can point me to?

Answer (score 2):

Look on Amazon.com or at your local bookstore for royalty free artwork. As an example: [http://www.amazon.com/Textile-Design-India-Royalty-Patterns/dp/4861002133/ref=sr_1_13?ie=UTF8&qid=1335922832&sr=8-13](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/4861002133)

Comment: i pretty much got it already, except the tricky part is going to be making the corners

Answer (score 2):

It's not hard for the corners you can do this easily in Photoshop by applying stroke and in stroke use pattern.

the stroke which is applied in the given site is called grungy texture you can get this texture [here](http://fbrushes.com/mixed-grungy-textures/), [here](http://www.inspiremonkey.com/2011/05/20-free-grunge-photoshop-patterns-sets/) & [here](http://blog.templatemonster.com/2011/11/03/free-grunge-photoshop-patterns/), then apply one of this on the stroke of your area.

you can get the art brush [here](http://all-free-download.com/photoshop-brushes/-art-brush.html).

what you have to do is create your area with the `rounded rectangle tool` then apply stroke by double clicking the layer, select `stroke` and then `pattern` from the sub drop down where color is selected by default, and make sure you have installed the downloaded pattern(just drag the pattern file which you have downloaded in case) and follow my screenshot.

I have used normal pattern just to make this clear to you.you can increase decrease stroke size.

[image]

hope this will help